# Dynamically Change Ordering of `fields` of Django Serializer using DynamicFieldsModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been using DynamicFieldsModelSerializer like so:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is None:
            request = self.context.get('request')
            if request is None:
                return
            fields = request.query_params.get('fields')
            if fields is None:
                return
            fields = fields.split(',')

        # Drop any fields that are not specified in the 'fields' argument
        allowed = set(fields)
        existing = set(self.fields.keys())
        for field_name in existing - allowed:
            self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

And the Serializer in question inherits the above class. Like so:

```
class OrderReportSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
card = CardSerializer(fields=('id', 'name'))
    board = BoardIDSerializer(source='card.board')
    customer = CustomerIdNameSerializer(source='card.customer')
    supplier = SupplierIdNameSerializer(source='card.supplier')
    quantity = serializers.CharField(source='card.quantity')
    .
    .
    .
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (  # fields whose source is Card
            'local_ordered_date',
            'card', 'country', 'customer', 'supplier',
            .
            .
            .
        )
```

And the view that uses aforementioned Serializer is following:

```
class SomeView():

    def table_view(self, queryset, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs["user"]
        """
        Override if different logic is required to display report data
        in table view.
        """
        report_model = Report.objects.get(user=user, report_type=self.__str__())
        fields = report_model.table_fields
        queryset = queryset.select_related(
            'card__board', 'card__customer', 'card__supplier',
            ...
            ...
        )
        if 'balance' in fields or 'invoice_total' in fields:
            ...
            ...

        return OrderReportSerializer(
            queryset, many=True, fields=fields).data
```

the `fields` is dynamic, such attribute of which is applied in the result to a certain degree. If `fields` have `('card', 'amount', 'customer')`, the response would show the proper data with those fields. However, the order of `fields` is crucial. When the `fields` have `('customer', 'card', 'amount')`, the result will still show data `('card', ,'amount', 'customer')`. I know that the only way to change the order is to modify the `fields` attribute of `class Meta` of the serializer. But it seems like there is no way to dynamically change the attribute value `fields` WITHIN THE META CLASS. What are some ways to circumvent this?

Comment: Why is the order important though? Be it a python dictionary, JSON object, XML, etc. whatever the serialized representation may be the order of key value pairs should not be important? If your client wants some order then surely they _know_ the order they want and can access the keys in that order??

Comment: The order is important because each item in the fields is a column of a table. And if the user wants to rearrange the columns so that the 'amount' column is placed on the far right, and the 'customer' column is placed on the far left, the API should apply such needs.